# After update Visual Studio IntelliSence works not fine

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense

After update, IntelliSence not focus on values. Can i fix that?

I want, that when i type values - intelli sence focus on it. But now i need to press UpArrowUp to focus on selected value.

[image: itellisence]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to reproduce your issue both in VS2017(15.9.17) and VS2019(16.3.9) and when I type the first letter of the value, it always focuses on the selected value. Please refer to the two pictures below:

VS2017

[image]

VS2019

[image]

`>>`So I think this issue is more related to VS IDE settings or environment and so on. You can try the following steps to troubleshoot your issue.

**Solution**

#1.reset your VS environment settings in case the changes to settings cause this behavior by `Tools-->Import and Export Settings-->Reset all settings`.

#2. try to use  [devenv /safemode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/safemode-devenv-exe?view=vs-2019) to start your project in case some changes in the update break the extensions which leads to affect intellisense functionality.

#3. try to close your VS instance,delete **.vs folder**,  and then restart your project.I suspect that one possibility is that the update destroys the **hidden .vs folder** (stored project settings as well as the smart-aware method).

#4. try to recreate a new project and then test with it. If successful, you can try migrating to a new project.

#5. try to [do a repair in VS Installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) in case the intellisense components are damaged.